# Passing pointer to local variable to function: is it safe?

Tags: c, pointers, stack

For example:

```
void func1(){
    int i = 123;
    func2(&i);
}
void func2(int *a){
    *a = 456;
}
```

When `func1` calling `func2`, a pointer to local variable is passed to `func2` -- the pointer is pointed to the stack. Is this safe for the rules of C?

Thanks.

Comment: Using a pointer to a variable after the variable is destroyed is unsafe. You aren't doing that here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safe to pass pointer to auto variable to function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798785/safe-to-pass-pointer-to-auto-variable-to-function)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The scope of `i` is `func1` and it outlives the call to `func2`. So it is perfectly safe.

Answer (score 7):

As stated in most of the answers before, it is perfectly safe to pass the pointer to `func2()` in your special case.

In a real world piece of software however, I consider this harmful as you don't have control on what `func2()` is doing with your variable. `func2()` may create an alias to its parameter to use it asynchronously at a later point in time. And at that time, the local variable `int i` may be gone when this alias is used later.

So from my point of view passing a pointer to a local (automatic) variable is extremely dangerous and should be avoided.

You may do so if you declare the variable in `func1()` as `static int i;`

In that case, it is ensured, that the memory for `i` won't get recycled and overwritten. However you will need to setup some Mutex locking for access control to this memory in a concurrent environment.

To illustrate this problem here is some code I just stumbled in yesterday while doing software testing at my customer. And yes, it crashes...

```
void func1()
{
  // Data structure for NVMemory calls
  valueObj_t NVMemObj;

  // a data buffer for eeprom write
  UINT8 DataBuff[25];
  // [..]
  /* Assign the data pointer to NV Memory object */
  NVMemObj.record = &DataBuff[0];
  // [..]
  // Write parameter to EEPROM.
  (void)SetObject_ASync(para1, para2, para3, &NVMemObj);
  return;
}

void SetObject_ASync(para1, para2, para3, valueObj_t *MemoryRef)
{
  //[..]
  ASyncQueue.CommandArray[ASyncQueue.NextFreeEntry].BufferPtr  = MemoryRef->record;
  //[..]
  return;
}
```

In this case, the data in the `DataBuff` is long gone when the pointer in `ASyncQueue.CommandArray[ASyncQueue.NextFreeEntry].BufferPtr` is used to store the data to the EEPROM.

To fix this code, it is at least necessary to declare `static UINT8 DataBuff[25];` Additionally, it shall be considered to also declare `static valueObj_t NVMemObj`as we don't know what the called function is doing with that pointer.

To put it briefly:
**TL;DR**

Even though it is legal in the C-language I consider it as harmful to pass pointers to automatic variables in a function call. You never know (and often you don't want to know) what exactly the called function does with the passed values. When the called function establishes an alias, you get in big trouble.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: "func2() may create an alias to its parameter to use it asynchronously at a later point in time". Yet the same could be said about malloced memory you pass into a function...it might create an alias to it which it tries to access after the caller later frees the memory. The point here is not the caller doing anything wrong, but the *called function* keeping references (where? in a global?) to it's own args that it re-uses in *later calls*. Also consider that it's a safer starting point as they don't need to be freed. TLDR; automatic variables=good. Functions keeping pointers to their args=bad.

Comment: @aaa90210 But the example is not using an malloc'ed memory. It is using a `static` buffer, which is guaranteed to exist during the entire lifetime of the process. So I agree, malloc or C++ `new` are dangerous. But static with mutexes isn't.

Comment: @deLock But `func2()` doesn't know whether the pointer argument it received is a pointer to statically-, automatically-, or dynamically-allocated memory, and what it's doing only works safely in the first of those three cases (it's only safe to stow away an alias pointer in global scope or something if it's a pointer to statically-allocated memory). So I'd say the locus of irresponsibility is in `func2()` assuming it can alias its pointer argument, not in `func1()` passing around the addresses of its local variables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is safe to pass a pointer to a local variable but you can't return a pointer to an automatic local variable from a function.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code is safe.

As long as the object's lifetime is not over, it's safe to pass local variables like you do.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this safe for the rules of C?

What you are doing is safe as the local variable is still valid and within the scope. Accessing the local varaible outside of its scope is undefined behvaior but this is totally fine

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can safely use `&i` till the time `i` is valid.

Now, as we can see `i` has a lifetime till the end of `func1()`. As, the `func2()` is being called from the `func1()` and the `func1()` has not yet finished execution, so, `i` is still valid.

That's why , usually passing the address of a local variable to another function is *usually* allowed (the variable's lifetime is not over) but, `return`ing the address of a local variable (immediately after `return`, local variables of the function cease to exist) is **not** allowed.

**TL;DR** :You can safely use `&i` as the argument of `func2()` as shown here.

Comment: *scope* applies to identifiers (not variables) and it means where that identifier is visible, so `i` is not in scope in `func2`. Perhaps you're looking for *lifetime*.